# When I try to import TensorFlow in Jupyter notebook I get the following error:

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, tensorflow2.0

In Jupyter Notebook, I have written the code as below:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import os
    import cv2
    import imghdr
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
    from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Precision, Recall, BinaryAccuracy
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
    from tensorflow import keras
```

When I run the code segment, below output is shown:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.autotrackable has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.autotrackable. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base_delegate has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base_delegate. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.data_structures has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.data_structures. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.graph_view has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.graph_view. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.util has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint_management. The old module will be deleted in version 2.9.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7248/3644658907.py in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 import os
      3 import cv2
      4 import imghdr
      5 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     49 from ._api.v2 import autograph
     50 from ._api.v2 import bitwise
---> 51 from ._api.v2 import compat
     52 from ._api.v2 import config
     53 from ._api.v2 import data

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py in <module>
     35 import sys as _sys
     36 
---> 37 from . import v1
     38 from . import v2
     39 from tensorflow.python.compat.compat import forward_compatibility_horizon

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py in <module>
     28 from . import autograph
     29 from . import bitwise
---> 30 from . import compat
     31 from . import config
     32 from . import data

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\__init__.py in <module>
     35 import sys as _sys
     36 
---> 37 from . import v1
     38 from . import v2
     39 from tensorflow.python.compat.compat import forward_compatibility_horizon

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py in <module>
     29 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import autograph
     30 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import bitwise
---> 31 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import config
     32 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import data
     33 from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import debugging

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\config\__init__.py in <module>
     12 from tensorflow.python.eager.context import LogicalDeviceConfiguration
     13 from tensorflow.python.eager.context import PhysicalDevice
---> 14 from tensorflow.python.eager.def_function import experimental_functions_run_eagerly
     15 from tensorflow.python.eager.def_function import experimental_run_functions_eagerly
     16 from tensorflow.python.eager.def_function import functions_run_eagerly

ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental_functions_run_eagerly' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function' (C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py)
```

The latest version of TensorFlow is to be installed in WLS2 for operating systems Windows 10 or above.
Refer: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
I have correctly followed the steps from the above link. Even though I am getting the issue repeatedly.

I tried installing TensorFlow in Conda environment, but the error persists.
[Installed TensorFlow in Conda env] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnRpZ.png)

My laptop has:
Windows 11 Home
Intel Graphics Card
python=3.11.1

Comment: Can you check if the problem persists outside of jupyter? what happens if you run your code in a terminal?

Comment: try downgrading python, tensorflow in finicky on newer versions of python

Comment: @SeaverOlson with latest version of python error is being generated -> 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: @SailajaRao Try running it on python=3.7

Comment: @SailajaRao, Tensorflow 2.11 is compatible with Python 3.7 - 3.10, kindly downgrade the version of python. Please find the tested build configurations [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations). Thank you!